# WHM/Cpanel Installing APC

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

What is the correct way to install APC on WHM and check that is is working? The steps I have carried out so far:

1. SSH on the server as root and run `yum install pcre-devel`
2. In WHM go to *PHP Configuration Editor*, Advanced Mode* and change **extension_dir** from `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613` to `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613`
3. In WHM go to `Module Installers`, click on *mange* next to *PHP Pecl*. Search for APC and install. (The last linetaht is returned says *The APC.so object is not in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613*)
4. In WHM go to *Configure PHP and SuExec* and make the *PHP 5 Handler* **dso**.

I have copied apc.php and the data seems to change however I don't have any apc options in php.ini in WHM. The only reference for in php.ini is under extension where it says `pdo.so, pdo_sqlite.so, sqlite.so, apc.so, pdo_mysql.so`.

How can I check that APC is installed correctly on WHM?

**Update**

The extension_dir for me ended up being `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`. APC is now in php.ini

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use phpinfo file on some test site:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

APC advertises itself in the result page.